# Linking CSS & bootstrap in Flask

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I've created a flask application and want to link Bootstrap and a custom css file. 
What's currently happening is that bootstrap is being applied, but my custom styles in styles.css aren't showing. I know that my file references are correct, because the bootstrap and custom css work independent of one another. How can I get them both to apply at the same time such that I can override the bootstrap defaults in my css?

My template.html looks like this:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/template.html" %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css" >
{% endblock %}
{% block title %} -- TITLE -- {% endblock %}
{% block navbar %}
-- NAVBAR HTML --
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
-- BODY TEXT HTML-- 
{% endblock %}
```

A content page looks like this:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block title %} -- TITLE -- {% endblock %}
<head>
    {% block head %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
</head>
{% block page_content %} PAGE CONTENT 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you try adding ! Important for your custom CSS files?

Comment: It might help if we could see the top of your bootstrap/template.html that template.html is extending